# Modifying Grails constraints during runtime

Tags: grails, grails-orm

**The problem:**

In my web application I defined some constraints. That I can save the domain class to "drafts" also when the constraint properties are not matching I set the constraint `nullable` to `true`. In the following process I can modify the object and after that to finalize the process I want to make a *full* validation. That means I want to **add** the `nullable:false` property.

- Question 1: Is there a way to extend/ change constraints during the runtime?
- Question 2: Is there a way to iterate through all constraints also when a domain class has nested constraints (e.g. other domain class references)

Thanks

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7526076/1442578

Answer (score 3):

- Answer 1: Yes you probably can.
- Answer 2: Yes.

So example:

```
    def user = new User()
    for(constraint in user.constraints) {
        constraint.value.setBlank(true)
        constraint.value.setNullable(false)
    }
```

For nested fields:

```
    for(constraint in user.someNestedFields.constraints) {
       ....
    }
```

But i would **not recommend to do so**. It looks like **bad architecture**.
To save your domain entity without validation just call `save(false)`.